# Syntax error when using parentheses with BETWEEN

Tags: mysql, select, between

I thought that the following would be the way I search for all calls placed in a 10 minute time frame

```
SELECT * FROM `call_log` WHERE start_time BETWEEN ('2012-05-01 17:50:00' AND '2013-05-01 18:00:00')
```

However when I run this query I get the following error

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'LIMIT 0, 30' at line 2
```

I am not sure what this currently means. The date formate is the same as above too.`y-m-d h:m:s`

Comment: @JohnConde: Why would MySQL be complaining about LIMIT?

Comment: As Robert Harvey mentioned, you don't use LIMIT in your problem query.  It looks like you didn't paste in the entire query that you're having problems with.  Can you do that?

Comment: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-between-clause.htm

Answer (score 1):

You don't need the parentheses:

```
SELECT * FROM `call_log` 
WHERE 
start_time BETWEEN '2012-05-01 17:50:00' AND '2013-05-01 18:00:00'
```

Comment: And, more specifically, using them causes MySQL to parse the contents of the parentheses as the first `BETWEEN` operand, so it complains that the second one is absent when it encounters the `LIMIT` clause.

Answer (score 0):

Below is the MySQL link around these type of queries and functions.  As someone noted (and beat me to it), you do not need the parentheses...

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html